# Should I recompile a table after I drop an Index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, sql-server-2012

I am in a process of dropping some unused indexes.

what I generally do is:

1. make sure the statistics are updated - maybe the index has not been used because the statistics have not been updated for a while
2. generate the drop index script and the create index script for each of the indexes involved
3. run the drop indexes commands
4. `update statistics tablename` -- so that the statistics are updated for the table index used to live
5. `sp_recompile 'tablename'` where the index used to live

Question: do I really need to do the sp_recompile?
Any suggestions?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping/Rebuilding an Index will result in invalidation of any cached execution plans using this table/Indexed view. And sql server will generate a new execution plan on next execution.

Same is true for Statistics, Updating statistics will result in invalidation of any cached execution plans. And sql server will generate a new execution plan on next execution.

Dont see any reason why you would explicitly tell sql server to recompile execution plans using this object(Table, view etc).

Comment: sp_recompile do not executes a recompilation of the objects itself. 
It deletes only all saved execution-plans. 
This forces an recompilation by the next call of the object (with the parameters of this next call).

Comment: this is the same thing that happens when indexes are rebuilt or statistics refreshed